# rubocop error on ExpandPathArguments

Tags: fastlane, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I have this rubocop error

```
Offenses:

fastlane-plugin-lizard.gemspec:1:12: C: Style/ExpandPathArguments: Use expand_path('lib', __dir__) instead of expand_path('../lib', __FILE__).
lib = File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^

10 files inspected, 1 offense detected
RuboCop failed!
Exited with code 1
```

How do I fix this error? cos follow rubocop advise I will get another error

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle check || bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3 --path vendor/bundle

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: 
[!] There was an error while loading `fastlane-plugin-lizard.gemspec`: cannot load such file -- fastlane/plugin/lizard/version
Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9. Bundler cannot continue.
```

Comment: I thought that everything to be bundled in the code had to be in the `lib` folder for the Gem to be created?

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
lib = File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
```

to

```
lib = File.expand_path("lib", __dir__)
```

Comment: As a general suggestion: read the entire question before answering. :-)